# How can I view the history on the trunk from my branch

Tags: tfs

View History on an file in a branch show only changes since the branch.  I need to go back further -- like how created the file in the first place.  I've also tried Sidekicks, and it doesn't seem to show history from before the branch either.

Short of hunting down the file in the trunk manually, is there a way to view a file's history from the time it was added to now following the path in the branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade to TFS 2010 for this support natively.  The 2010 upgrade is well worth the time for many reasons, this being one of them.

Comment: Where in Visual Studio / TFS 2010 is this support natively?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: When you view history, those files that have history in other branches should show a history tree rather than simply a linear history.

Answer (score 1):

I've used an addon [TFS follow branch history](http://tfsbranchhistory.codeplex.com/) the UI is a bit clunky but will get you what you're looking for. It only shows the branched history for a file but won't recurse to all files in a directory.